# React native array map insert at beginning

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native

I wrote an animated list component:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropType from 'prop-types';
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable-promise';
import {FlatList, View} from 'react-native';
import {observable, action, runInAction} from "mobx"
import {observer} from 'mobx-react';
import TransitionGroup, {FadeInOutTransition} from 'react-native-transitiongroup';
import arrayDiff from 'arraydiff';

class AnimatedListItem extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        animationOut: PropType.string.isRequired,
        animationIn: PropType.string.isRequired,
        duration: PropType.number.isRequired
    };

    tempHeight = 0;
    locked = false;

    componentDidAppear(callback) {
        this.componentWillEnter(callback);
    }

    componentDidEnter(callback) {
        this.refs.Item[this.props.animationIn](this.props.duration).then(() => callback());
    }

    componentWillLeave(callback) {
        this.locked = true;
        this.refs.Item.stopAnimation();
        this.refs.Item.transition({height: this.tempHeight, opacity: 1, scale: 1}, {height: 0, opacity: 0, scale: 0}, this.props.duration, 'ease').then(callback).catch(console.error);
        //this.refs.Item[this.props.animationOut](this.props.duration).then(() => callback());
    }

    _onLayout(event) {
        const {height} = event.nativeEvent.layout;
        if (!this.locked) this.tempHeight = height;
    }

    render() {
        return (<Animatable.View ref='Item' onLayout={this._onLayout.bind(this)}>
            {this.props.children}
        </Animatable.View>);
    }

}

@observer
class AnimatedList extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        data: PropType.array.isRequired,
        renderItem: PropType.func.isRequired,
        keyExtractor: PropType.func.isRequired,
        inAnimation: PropType.string.isRequired,
        outAnimation: PropType.string.isRequired,
        style: PropType.any,
        duration: PropType.number,
        delay: PropType.number
    };

    @observable keyExtractor = this.props.keyExtractor;
    @observable data = [];
    @observable duration = this.props.duration || 1000;
    @observable outAnimation = this.props.outAnimation;
    @observable inAnimation = this.props.inAnimation;
    _renderItem = this.props.renderItem;
    delay = this.props.delay || 100;

    queue;
    actionIsRunning = false;

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setProps(this.props);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
        this.setProps(props);
    }

    setProps(props) {
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            if (this.actionIsRunning) {
                this.queue = props;
                return;
            }
            this.queue = null;
            this.actionIsRunning = true;
            runInAction(() => {
                this.duration = props.duration || 1000;
                this.outAnimation = props.outAnimation;
                this.inAnimation = props.inAnimation;
                this.delay = props.delay;
                this.keyExtractor = props.keyExtractor;
            });
            const differences = arrayDiff(this.data.toJS(), props.data.toJS(), (a, b) => {
                const aKey = this.keyExtractor(a);
                const bKey = this.keyExtractor(b);
                return aKey === bKey;
            });
            console.log("ADIFF: " + JSON.stringify(differences));
            this.applyDifferences(differences).then(() => {
                console.log("NEWLIST: " + JSON.stringify(this.data));
                this.actionIsRunning = false;
                if (this.queue) this.setProps.bind(this)(this.queue);
            }).catch(e => console.error(e));
        });
    }

    async applyDifferences(differences) {
        for (let diff of differences) {
            if (!diff.type) continue;
            await new Promise((resolve) => requestAnimationFrame(resolve));
            if (diff.type === 'remove' && diff.index !== undefined && diff.howMany !== undefined) {
                runInAction(() => {
                    this.data.splice(diff.index, diff.howMany);
                });
            }
            if (diff.type === 'move' && diff.from !== undefined && diff.to !== undefined) {
                runInAction(() => {
                    moveInThisArray(this.data, diff.from, diff.to);
                });
            }
            if (diff.type === 'insert' && diff.index !== undefined && Array.isArray(diff.values)) {
                const argArray = [diff.index, 0];
                for (let value of diff.values) {
                    argArray.push(value);
                }
                runInAction(() => {
                    this.data.splice.apply(this.data, argArray);
                });
            }
            await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, this.delay));
        }
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, this.duration));
    }


    /**
     * @typedef {Object} FlatListRenderInfo
     * @property {Object} item
     * @property {Number} index
     * @property {Object} separators
     */

    /**
     *
     * @param {FlatListRenderInfo} info
     */
    renderItem(info) {
        //console.log(this.keyExtractor(info.item));
        return (
            <AnimatedListItem animationOut={this.outAnimation} animationIn={this.inAnimation} duration={this.duration}
                              key={this.keyExtractor(info.item)}>
                {this._renderItem(info)}
            </AnimatedListItem>);
    }

    render() {
        return (<TransitionGroup>
            {this.data.toJS().map((item, index) => {
                return this.renderItem({
                    item: item,
                    index: index,
                    separators: {}
                });
            })}
        </TransitionGroup>)
    }

}

function moveInThisArray(arr, old_index, new_Index) {
    if (new_Index >= arr.length) {
        let k = new_Index - arr.length;
        while ((k--) + 1) {
            arr.push(undefined);
        }
    }
    arr.splice(new_Index, 0, arr.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);
    return arr;
}

export default AnimatedList;
```

The most of my code works as expected. But I have a little problem, if I add an element at the beginning of the array, it will render at the end of my list. I think maybe my usage of `Array.map` is wrong. There is no problem with the array, if I print the array to the console, it has the right order. I already noticed this problem in my last problem, but ignored it because in my last project it dosen't mattered in which order the elements were, but this time it matters. Is there an alternative to use instead `Array.map` to solve the problem? Or what should I do?

Comment: have you try to use unshift instead of push?

Comment: Because it should not push every time at the beginning. The beginning was just an example. It could also be at the second position etc.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then you want your array to map last item to the first, right? If so, then using [Array.prototype.reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) prior to the map should do the trick. Like so...

```
render() {
    return (<TransitionGroup>
        {this.data.toJS()
            .reverse()
            .map((item, index) => {
            return this.renderItem({
                item: item,
                index: index,
                separators: {}
            });
        })}
    </TransitionGroup>)
}
```

Comment: No, hm maybe my question is a little bit confusing. When I push **as example** an Item to the top, It won't render at the top until I refresh the hole component. It also happens when I push an Item to the middle or somewhere else. It renders the newest Item to the bottom but It should render the items to the right order without rerendering everything.

Comment: Ah! yeah, I didn't understand that to be the problem at all. Ha! Let me take a closer look.